# What is the purpose of defining methods in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the purpose of defining methods inside a model like the example here? What does this get me? I was under the impression that only the fields of a model are defined in the model.

```
class Bean
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :roast, type: String
  field :origin, type: String
  field :quantity, type: Float

  has_many :pairings
  #  has_many :pastries

  def pastries
    Pastry.find pastry_ids
  end
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :pastries

  def pastry_ids
    pastry_ids_array = []
    self.pairings.each do |one_pairing|
      if one_pairing.pastry_id
        pastry_ids_array.push one_pairing.pastry_id
      end 
    end
    pastry_ids_array 
  end

  def pastry_ids=(list)
    self.pairings.destroy
    list.each do |pastry_id|
      self.pairings.create(pastry_id: pastry_id)
    end
  end

  # some way of showing a list
  def pastry_list
    pastries_string = ""
    pastries.each do |one_pastry|
      pastries_string += ", " + one_pastry.name
    end
    pastries_string.slice(2,pastries_string.length - 1)
    pastries_string
  end

end
```

Comment: What is the purpose of defining methods *ever*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you know enough ruby but let's say you don't. This is a basic Class question? Defining methods on a model it's like having an helper. Let's say that you have

```
class CanadianPopulation 

  attr_accessor :population, :number_of_french_speaker, :number_of_english_speaker

  def initialize(a,b,c)
    @population = a
    @number_of_french_speaker = b
    @number_of_english_speaker = c
  end

  def total_people_that_have_a_different_mother_tongue
    #Canadian who speak english or french but have a different mother tongue
    self.population - (self.number_of_french_speaker + self.number_of_english_speaker)
  end
end

census_2014 = CanadianPopulation.new(34_000_000, 4_000_000, 12_000_000)
```

let's say that you didn't have the method `total_people_that_have_a_different_mother_tongue`how will you do to retrieve the total number of Canadians that have a different mother tongue? you will do the caculation yourself like for a view

```
<p>Canadian who speak english or french but have a different mother tongue
<br>
<%= @census = @census.population - (@census.number_of_english_speaker + @census.number_of_french_speaker) %>
</p>
```

Your view or your controller shouldn't do much logic (calculations) so that's one of the reason why you have a method inside the model (or class) it should be like this

```
<p>Canadian who speak english or french but have a different mother tongue
<br>
<%= @census.total_people_that_have_a_different_mother_tongue %>
</p>
```

For the second part of your question what does those methods do. `rails c -s` on your terminal than call or create a new instance model Bean and check to see what it does (the output/results)

```
Bean.first
b = _
b.pastries
b.pastry_ids
b.pastry_list
```

edit: @paul-richer recommends to **maintain a thin controller**

Comment: If it didn't make the post look gross, I might recommend bolding the paragraph about maintaining a thin controller.